# Multi-country use?

Tags: user-experience

Our organization has a branch in the US and one in Canada. Can we use Civi for both combined and just filter info by country? For example, entering donor info in Canadian currency, then our Canadian accountant pulling that for the bookkeeping, and having our US accountant pull US donation info, etc. I just want to make sure that we can use it to streamline everything before committing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use one of the demo sites eg http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/ to test out some of these things. Eg at http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/search?reset=1 you can see that Currency is one of the filterable options, and I fully expect that you could set up Report for each of them with the currency pre-filtered.

Comment: I noticed that when I was playing around with things, but wanted to check with people who were more familiar with things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short - **yes**, this is supported in CiviCRM!

Filtering by currency and/or country is doable on the three reports I checked, including the most commonly used contribution reports (Contribution Summary, Contribution Detail).  Here's a screenshot of the filters for a report:
[image]

Filtering by currency and/or country is also possible from search (these two screenshots are two parts of the same page, "Advanced Search"):
[image]
[image]

Comment: @leslieRolling - please mark the answer as "accepted" to help future visitors to this site with the same question!